# Database SQL Query Error Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I am trying to update a table and I keep getting the error that I have an error in my SQL syntax. It is showing a red line under "foreign". Can anyone see anything wrong with this line?

update section foreign key (course_id) references course(course_id) on delete cascade

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot UPDATE a foreign key, you can alter it.

`ALTER TABLE section
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_ section
FOREIGN KEY (course_id)
REFERENCES course(course_id) on delete cascade`